# Linting errors in js2-mode that seem to *not* be coming from flycheck?

Tags: javascript, emacs, spacemacs, flycheck

I'm using emacs with the Spacemacs configuration (javascript layer enabled, syntax-checking *not* enabled). When in js2-mode I am finding that the wrong linting is happening (ie I have a `.eslintrc` file at my project root and its config is being ignored - running eslint from the cli gives me zero errors but errors appear in-buffer).

[image: eslint from the cli shows no errors]

I'm a bit at a loss at this point on *what* could even be generating these linting errors. As far as I know, they must be coming from flycheck (I note [this line](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b7e51d70aa3fb81df2da6dc16d9652a002ba5e6b/layers/%2Blang/javascript/packages.el#L60) in the javascript layer code even though flycheck isn't mentioned in the docs nor can I find where its invoked from). However, I can swear that flycheck isn't on. I am quite sure of this because

- I've tried manually toggling off `flycheck-mode` through the interactive minibuffer
- I've run `describe-mode` and ensured that there's no mention of flycheck, linting, or syntax checking
- `flycheck-verify-setup` reports `Flycheck Mode is disabled.`
- I've added a hook `(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook (lambda () (message "entered flycheck mode")))` that never gets triggered

So where could these errors in my buffer *possibly* be coming from?.

[image: Eslint errors about missing semi colon and trailing comma]

[image: Errors show up in minibuffer]

Here is a `.spacemacs` excerpt

```
 dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
 '(
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
     ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
     ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     javascript
     html
     helm
     auto-completion
     git
     better-defaults
     colors
     ;; emacs-lisp
     markdown
     clojure
     ;; org
     ;; (shell :variables shell-default-position 'bottom)
     ;; spell-checking
     ;; react
     ;; syntax-checking
        version-control
     )
 ;; List of additional packages that will be installed without being
 ;; wrapped in a layer. If you need some configuration for these
 ;; packages, then consider creating a layer. You can also put the
 ;; configuration in `dotspacemacs/user-config'.
 dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(
                                                                        paredit
                                                                        editorconfig
                                                                        writeroom-mode
                                                                        tide
                                                                        csharp-mode
                                                                        elisp-format
                                                                        ;; powershell
                                                                        omnisharp
                                                                        gist
                                                                        parinfer
                                                                        ag )
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual errors?

Comment: @AronGriffis what do you mean? They're linting errors in my js files. Stuff like "there's no semi colon" when I've got that rule disabled in my `.eslintrc` and the cli (properly) doesn't report it. There are no Emacs errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors come directly from `js2-mode`.

You can turn them off by setting these 2 in your config:

```
(setq js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil
      js2-mode-show-strict-warnings nil)
```